# packer build cannot ssh to aws instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, packer

The following configuration will spin up an instance but fails to connect it... but the same key, vpc-id, subnet id, and security group id works in test kitchen without issues.

```
{
  "variables": {
  "aws_access_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "aws_secret_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
},
    "builders": [{
        "type": "amazon-ebs",
        "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
        "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
        "region": "us-east-1",
        "source_ami": "ami-146e2a7c",
        "instance_type": "t2.micro",
        "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
        "ami_name": "packer-example {{timestamp}}",
        "ssh_keypair_name": "xxx",
        "ssh_private_key_file": "xxx.pem",
        "vpc_id": "vpc-xxxxxxx",
        "subnet_id": "subnet-xxxxxxx",
        "security_group_id": "sg-xxxxxxx",
        "associate_public_ip_address": "true"

    }]
}
```

I get the following debug errors:

```
2016/12/17 20:10:50 packer: 2016/12/17 20:10:50 [DEBUG] SSH handshake err: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [publickey none], no supported methods remain
2016/12/17 20:10:50 packer: 2016/12/17 20:10:50 [DEBUG] Detected authentication error. Increasing handshake attempts.
2016/12/17 20:10:57 packer: 2016/12/17 20:10:57 [INFO] Attempting SSH connection...
2016/12/17 20:10:57 packer: 2016/12/17 20:10:57 reconnecting to TCP connection for SSH
2016/12/17 20:10:57 packer: 2016/12/17 20:10:57 handshaking with SSH
2016/12/17 20:10:59 packer: 2016/12/17 20:10:59 handshake error: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
2016/12/17 20:10:59 packer: 2016/12/17 20:10:59 [DEBUG] SSH handshake err: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
2016/12/17 20:10:59 ui error: ==> amazon-ebs: Error waiting for SSH: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
2016/12/17 20:10:59 ui: ==> amazon-ebs: Terminating the source AWS instance...
```

Given that this works in test kitchen with no extra variables I'm wondering what I'm missing? Any ideas?

Comment: you're sure you booted the ec2 instance with the same SSH public key?  There's no chance you put the wrong public key on the instance?  That's what this would usually mean.

Comment: Problem solved - wrong default username :)

Comment: @TyMac then you should answer your own question and mark you answer as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was the wrong default username.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by not forgetting to add the public_key_pair (of the aws account)
I had the same error message "amazon-ebs: Error waiting for SSH: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain" and problem was that I had forgotten to provide SSH_KEYPAIR_NAME to the dockerized Packer. After adding kaypair name, it works now!